# Assigning a var to temp var doesn't stop origianal var from changing

Tags: javascript, node.js

Alright stackoverflow,

I've been working hours on solving an issue in javascript (writing in NodeJS server) but I really don't get it.

This is what happens:

```
var data = {x: 50};
var temp = data;
temp.x = 100;
console.log(data.x);
//logs 100
```

I have tested this exact code and it really shows `100`.

My question:

How do I clone a var to a temp one and change the temp var without the original changing along.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to clone the original object. This is because storing the object in another variable doesn't create a new object with the same properties as the previous one; it just creates a reference to the same object. Sadly, there aren't any built in solutions to get around this, but there are a few solutions. Here some that come to mind:

```
var temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); // clones the object using a hack
```

Or:

```
var temp = {}; // creates a new object and gives it all the same properties as
               // the old one.
for(prop in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        temp[prop] = data[prop];
    }
}
```

Not to be self-promoting, but I've written up a blog post about this subject which goes into a little more detail. You can find [here](http://heyjavascript.com/4-creative-ways-to-clone-objects/).

Comment: First line works perfectly, Thank you. - will accept answer in 10 minutes

Comment: Yeah, that's true. More of an exploit. :)

Answer (score 3):

Assigning an object to a variable does not make a copy of the object.  It just creates another reference to the same object.   Both variables will then point to the exact same object and changing properties of either one (`data` and `temp` in your example) will change the exact same object.

To make a copy of an object, one has to actually make an explicit copy of the object by copying all the properties to a new object.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I was not aware of this. It explains alot of my problems!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`clone`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#clone) method of the underscore library to easily clone an object.

```
var temp = _.clone(data);
```